# Number of phrases of LZ compression

Tags: information-theory, data-compression, lempel-ziv

It is known that for the number $c(n)$ of phrases / tupel of the LZ compression for binary words of length $n$ the following relation holds:
$$c(n)\leq\frac{n}{(1-\epsilon_n)\log_2 n}$$
With $\epsilon_n\to 0$ for $n\to\infty$.

The proof is made in [Thomas & Cover: Elements of Information Theory](ftp://ftp.esat.kuleuven.ac.be/pub/sista/decock/voor_xander/referenties/Cover&Thomas/12.pdf) (Lemma 12.10.1, page 320 in the linked chapter).

I tried to generalize it to an alphabet of size $k$ by adjust the proof step by step, but I failed. So, my question:

How can I prove that the number $c(n)$ of phrases / tupel of the LZ compression is bounded by
$$c(n)\leq\frac{n}{(1-\epsilon_n)\log_k n}$$
for all words of length $n$ over an alphabet of size $k$ with $\epsilon_n\to0$ for $n\to\infty\;?$

Comment: Sounds like an exercise. I suggest you keep trying.

Comment: If you mean an axercise for a course or something like that, it is not. But even if it were, your comment do not help me at all.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed us the partial proof you have constructed so far, and where you think it broke down, we could give you better help.  As it is, we can't tell what concepts you are having trouble with, so there's not anything useful that we can say.

Comment: @WanderingLogic my question was more about some other way to prove this theorem.. like the answer i accept or maybe induction. Therefore i omit my try since it contains a lot of big expressions (see $n_k$ in the proof for $k=2$)

Comment: Really? A down vote for that question? A lot of stupid questions pass that site and this question was down voted.. thanks.

Comment: Danny, I didn't downvote your question, but a suggestion for the future: I think questions fare better when you show us in the question what you've tried.  For instance, did you try looking for counterexamples (picking some special cases of specific kinds of strings, working out what the compression ratio would be for them, and seeing if they lead to any counterexamples)? Did you try proving by induction?  When you tried to generalize the proof and adjust it step-by-step, in what way did it fail? How do you know your claim is even true? This may help others give you more concrete suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to redo the proof for this, simply note that $n$ symbols of an alphabet of size $k$ can be represented with $n \log_2(k)$ bits.  The Lempel-Ziv bound is then:

$\mbox{# phrases} \leq \frac{n log_2 k}{(1-\epsilon_{n \lg k})log_2(n \log_2 k)}$

Dividing numerator and denominator by $\log_2 k$ then gives:

$\mbox{# phrases} \leq \frac{n}{(1-\epsilon_{n \lg k})\left(log_k(n) + \log_2(\log_2(k))/log_2(k)\right)}$

Since $\epsilon_n \longrightarrow 0$ as $n \longrightarrow \infty$, the result follows.

Comment: Thanks, i thought about something like that when i'm asking this question.